# Lenovo ThinkPad P52 + Ubuntu Studio; Doesn rogognize secon monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors

My P52 + Ubuntu Studio cant find second monitor (Dell U2719DC).
 
Tried to find solution from net but no success. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: As the first step to debug it - try switching video card mode in BIOS

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Section 5 of this [Guide by Lenovo](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/LenovoThinkpad_P53_P73_Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_Installation_v1.0.pdf). It helped me getting external monitors to work on my P53.

In short. Installing the proprietary NVIDIA drivers should fix your external monitor. The guide suggests `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430`, however there are newer versions of the driver (435 and 440) available. I am using 440 and it works.

Regards

Comment: Thank you so much. Did this. Now I can see the 27" Dell, but it's disabled. How can I enable it?

Comment: This worked for me. I'm on a Thinkpad P52, running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, and my second monitor (which didn't connect via HDMI) is a 27" Acer G276HL. I hope this helps anyone having the same problem.